# Async issues with fetch API Calls - console.log() works but not setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a fetch POST that gets a token:

```js
fetch(proxyUrl + 'https://myComp.csod.com/services/api/oauth2/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
})
```

I console log the token without any issues with adding a *then* after the fetch:

```js
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data.access_token));
```

But when I do the same as above, but with a setState, it does not work and my state is empy:

```js
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => this.setState({token: data.access_token}));
```

Above state will be empty, but when I console log, the token will be printed out. How come?

Comment: are you determining state is empty by using a console.log? you should use the setState callback to do this. `this.setState({token: data.access_token}, () => { console.log(this.state)});`

Comment: Not sure if this is needed, but to clarify what Jacob said... I think it setState is working correctly, but the way you verify/test that it's working might the problem.. so if this is confusing, share how you noticed that setState didn't work for you.

Comment: How can you be sure your state isn't updated?

Comment: Jacob was right. State was correct - it was the way I tested it that was wrong (console.log after setting the state). Thanks all.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't add any kind of explanation. This is because the setState is asynchronous to the rest of the code and will be represent correctly before the next rerender. If you need to run code after the state is set but before the next rerender you can add it to the callback.